# Google sheets shared macro file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have about 70 different google sheets files and they need to be separate files. They all use the same macros, right not I am coping the macros into each sheet file and if I need to change something I have to change it in the macros for each of the 70 files.  Is there a way like a dll that I can have all files have access to the same macro file. There are multiple different macros in this file and are quite complex, they do things onEdit and they add a new menu, etc.

Comment: use https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries

Comment: I would reconsider moving to individual sheets.  If you don't know enough to do the code then perhaps you are making a mistake in your decision to move sheets to individual files.  You cannot execute onEdits remotely and you use them in a library

Answer (score 0):

### You can deploy a [standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)

How to apply it depends on your situation, but assuming you write once something like:

```
const spreadsheetIds = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"];

function applyToAllSheets(){
 spreadsheetIds.forEach(function(id){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
   runFunction(id);
  })
}

function runFunction(){
  ss.getActiveRange().setValue("Hello World");
}
```

You can modify the content of `runFunction()` and then, when you run `applyToAllSheets()` - `runFunction()` will be executed for all spreadsheets with the ids specified in `const spreadsheetIds`.